# How to monitor data that has entered one table but not another table?

Tags: sql-server

I've to monitor SMSes that enter a table say "tbl_transaction" but not say "tbl_sms_sent". How would I do that? Assume there is a direct relationship between two tables. I assume something like A intersection B compliment would do the job but I am not sure how to convert this relational algebra to sql query.

Comment: "_Assume there is a direct relationship between two tables._" Does _direct relation_ mean one table has foreign key referencing the other? Or, like, that both tables have same columns defining the particular SMS?

Comment: there is a foreign key referencing the other. In practice, it's not the case but I'll manage for that case myself, if I fail you guys are there.

Comment: What are you looking for in your desired results? Rows that exist in tbl_transaction but there does not exist a corresponding row in tbl_sms_sent? What are the table definitions?

Comment: [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

> I've to monitor SMSes that enter a table say "tbl_transaction" but not say "tbl_sms_sent". How would I do that?

So it sounds like you want a list of rows that exist in `tbl_transaction` but not `tbl_sms_sent`. There's a few different ways you can do this.

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` clause in a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * -- Don't use * in practice, actually list out your table columns
FROM tbl_transaction AS T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 AS DoesExist
    FROM tbl_sms_sent AS S
    WHERE T.KeyField = S.KeyField
)
```

You can also accomplish the same results with an `OUTER JOIN` and `WHERE` clause to keep unmatched rows like so:

```
SELECT * -- Don't use * in practice, actually list out your table columns
FROM tbl_transaction AS T
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_sms_sent AS S
    ON T.KeyField = S.KeyField
WHERE S.KeyField IS NULL
```

Both options will result in the same outcome of rows, but the execution plans to run the query will typically differ. Many times the first way will be more performant [for a few reasons](https://erikdarlingdata.com/why-not-exists-makes-more-sense-than-left-joins/) including eliminating the need for a residual filter after the join. But you should always test and see what ends up working best in your environment for the actual use case it's for.

Comment: turns out there is no primary key referenced in other table in tbl_transactions.

Comment: @achhainsan so you're saying there's no relation between the two tables?

Comment: yes no relations. there is no way this tbl_transactions is connected to any other table, that's weird tbh. what is the purpose of this? its primary key isn't referenced in any other table.

Comment: @achhainsan a transactions type table typically has foreign key references to other tables, not the other way around. Without seeing the table definition, I wouldn't be able to tell you which fields would potentially be foreign key fields to other table.

Comment: you want me to get fired? :)

Comment: @achhainsan sorry, but that's the minimum requirement of information when posting a question on here. You can obviously obfuscate the names to a reasonable degree, if you need. Otherwise there's not much else anyone can do for you. The code examples I provided still apply, you just need to figure out which fields to relate on, which again, probably are foreign key columns in the transactions table and primary key columns in the other tables like `tbl_sms_sent`.